# Reading Data file and outputting to another file

Tags: java

Im trying to make a program that reads data from a text file which contains student names and scores they got on a test. I want to output it in this sort of way

Im starting off by trying to read the txt file so I can then re arrange them and then outputting it into another file but im not sure what im doing wrong. Instead it prints into the exe instead of the file I want it to print to.

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadConsole {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the file name with extention : ");
            File file = new File(input.nextLine());

            input = new Scanner(file); //scans the file


            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JOln.png)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `System.out` `PrintStream`, you can create a `PrintStream` that writes to a file:

```
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("output.txt"));
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = input.nextLine();
   output.println(line);
}
```

Remember to close both `input Scanner` and `output PrintStream`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the file name with extention : ");
    File file = new File(input.nextLine());

    try (Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file); // scans the file
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("c:/output.txt"))) {

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            output.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you edit it into the code im not sure how to do it without getting errors

Comment: is there anyway to automatically make it read Data.txt without having to put it in on the exe?

Comment: Instead of creating a file based on input text, create with the path to Data.txt: File file = new File("Data.txt");